# A-spaces vs generalized spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, generalized-smooth-spaces

$\newcommand\Set{\mathit{Set}}$I've been searching about the notions of smooth generalized spaces and I come across with two definitions that seem very good ones.

John Baez and Alexander Hoffunung give the following definition (that can be found in their article: "[Convenient categories of smooth spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.1704)"):

**Definition**. Given a concrete site $D$, a generalized space or $D$-space is a concrete sheaf $X:D^\text{op}\rightarrow \Set$.

On the other hand M. V. Losik, given a site $A$, defines an $A$-space as a set $X$ with a "categorical" atlas. This atlas is basically the colimit of a diagram $C\rightarrow \Set$, where $C$ is a subcategory of $A$. This definition is better explained in his article: "[Categorical differential geometry](http://www.numdam.org/item/CTGDC_1994__35_4_274_0)". Sorry for the vague definition on an $A$-space, if I write all the details this question would be much larger.

The thing that I don't get is the relationship of this definitions, i.e., if the definition of Baez implies Losik, Losik implies Baez or neither? Is there a reason for not using Losik's notion of generalized space, to develop categorical differential geometry?

Comment: There is of course a much older definition.  If the space is a subspace of a manifold in a natural way, then you can inherit the smooth structure from the ambient space, using local extendability.   I find this is often sufficient for my purposes.